# Do I need to update secondary DNS server when adding new host (A) record or DNS record?

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2008, replication

In Windows Server 08 do I need to update the secondary DNS server when adding a new host (A) record or only the primary? When adding new DNS records do I have to add it to the other DNS servers? Does replication only happen when the files are changed and not when new ones are added?

Answer (score 0):

No. In a correct configuration, the change will propagate to the other server no matter from which one you make the addition. So adding the A-record in any server should suffice.